# Firestore orderBy query

Tags: database, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an function in my flutter app that searches among users with specified filters and range. Here is the full view of the function;

```
Future<Query> searchInfluencersWithQuery(
    Map<String, dynamic> query,
    String platform,
    String userTier,
    List<TierModel> tierList,
  ) async {
    Query<Map<String, dynamic>> usersQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('influencers')
        .orderBy(
          "socialMediaHandler.${platform.toLowerCase()}.followerCount",
          descending: true,
        )
        .where("platforms", arrayContains: platform.toLowerCase());
    List ranges = TierRepository().getTierRange(userTier, tierList);
    int lowerBound = ranges[0];
    int upperBound = ranges[1];
    usersQuery = usersQuery.where(
      'socialMediaHandler.${platform.toLowerCase()}.followerCount',
      isLessThan: upperBound,
    );
    usersQuery = usersQuery.where(
      'socialMediaHandler.${platform.toLowerCase()}.followerCount',
      isGreaterThan: lowerBound,
    );
    if (query["location"] != null && query["location"] != "") {
      usersQuery = usersQuery.where('country', isEqualTo: query["location"]);
    }
    if (query["isActive"] != null && query["isActive"] != false) {
      usersQuery = usersQuery.where('isActive', isEqualTo: query["isActive"]);
    }
    if (query["gender"] != null && query["gender"].length == 1) {
      usersQuery = usersQuery.where("gender", isEqualTo: query["gender"][0]);
    }
    usersQuery = usersQuery.orderBy("subscriptionPlan", descending: true);
    return usersQuery;
  }
```

I want to order the last query data by subscriptionPlan which is one of the 0,1,2,3 int values(free, gold, diamond, platinum)
But this orderBy query doesnt work. It's like firestore just ignoring it.
Can you guys help me about this issue? How can i fix this?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations), *"if you have a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field"*.

If you include a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field. That means that in your case:

```dart
    Query<Map<String, dynamic>> usersQuery =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('influencers').where("platforms", arrayContains: platform.toLowerCase());

    List ranges = TierRepository().getTierRange(userTier, tierList);
    int lowerBound = ranges[0];
    int upperBound = ranges[1];

    usersQuery = usersQuery
        .where(
          'socialMediaHandler.${platform.toLowerCase()}.followerCount',
          isLessThan: upperBound,
        )
        .where(
          'socialMediaHandler.${platform.toLowerCase()}.followerCount',
          isGreaterThan: lowerBound,
        )
        .orderBy(
          "socialMediaHandler.${platform.toLowerCase()}.followerCount",
          descending: true,
        );
```